# Having trouble standardizing pages alignment

Tags: html, web, alignment, dreamweaver

I'm new here so apologies if this is the wrong spot or I missed the answer somewhere else.

Pretty simple question. I built this website in Dreamweaver, coded myself but I'm having a issue with the pages aligning differently. They should all be dead Center but a couple are shifted slightly. I thought it as a margin error but they are all set to '0'. In fact as far as I can see everything is the same.

I've spend all night trying to get every page to display the same (bar content if course with no luck). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the URL:

www.sfcitibrokers.net

It's still a work in progress but I don't want to continue till I fix this and find out what the problem is. Basic I know, I'm not a programmer really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The value of text-align is not correct in p.text4.

Comment: I just changed it to 'left' and it's fixed. Thank you so much! I know, so simple but I spent literally hours trying different things. Got to remember how important the style sheet is. Thank you again for your help, impressed at how fast you could spot that.

Answer (score 1):

In 'Neighborhoods/Availability' page, you have a  `class=skype_c2c_menu_container`.

Inside your html page where you have the skype link,

`<div class="skype_c2c_menu_container notranslate" ...`

you have it as `id="skype_c2c_menu_container"`. It should be `class=` **not** `id=`.  This causes some expansion in the div.  That is one thing I saw.

Another, 'Tenants' page, there are a number of code mistakes.  To give one,

`<td width="511" bgcolor="#708090" ;="">`.  You have a number of those code mishmash that contribute to your html behaving strangely.

Comment: That's strange. There shouldn't be any links to Skype at all. Thanks for point out a few of those, I will trawl though the code and see if I can find some.

'Tenants' does seem particularly messy. Having an issue with the address et al on the right appearing a little higher than on other pages though the code that proceeds the text is the same.